# Get from store without triggering an update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a parent component which (simplified) looks as follows

```
export default class ProductGrid extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
  renderProducts() {
    return this.props.products.map(product => (
      <Product {...product} />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderProducts()}</div>;
  }
}
```

In my `Product` component, however, I must subscribe to the current selection, or at least the number of items currently selected.

**Here's the trouble**: due to subscribing to this piece of data in the redux store, whenever my selection number changes, *it will result in every product that is currently visible updating*

While I could implement a custom `shouldComponentUpdate` and omit this property, it still runs that custom lifecycle hook. My page can have upwards of 200 products on it, so this can cause a problem.

I am using this information solely on drop and was wondering if it is possible to simply grab this information "in that moment" from the redux store without subscribing to changes. For example, similar to `redux-saga`:

```
onDragStart = () => {
  const selectedCount = select(({ products: { selected } }) => selected.length);
  if (selectedCount) {
    // whatever here
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You could add `static contextTypes = { store: PropTypes.object }` and then `this.context.store.getState()` and inspect whatever you need to.

Comment: That's a good idea, is it possible to implement this as a HOC without causing it to update?

Answer (score 1):

In response to your, "is it possible to implement this as a HOC without causing it to update": Here is a quick outline of a HoC that will provide store as a property to whatever component you pass it.

```
function myHoC(WrappedComponent) {
  const classToExtend = WrappedComponent.prototype instanceof React.PureComponent
    ? React.PureComponent
    : React.Component

  class NonUpdatingStoreProvider extends classToExtend {
    static contextTypes = {
      store: PropTypes.object,
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          store={ this.context.store }
          { ...this.props }
        />
      )
    }
  }

  NonUpdatingStoreProvider.WrappedComponent = WrappedComponent
  NonUpdatingStoreProvider.displayName = `NonUpdatingStoreProvider(${WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name})`

  return NonUpdatingStoreProvider
}
```

Note: The returned component will obviously update like other components, regular or pure depending on what you pass to it. It will not cause updates in reaction to store changes though.

If you don't want the store passed to components you could just pass the `store.getState` method or whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

If your component `ProductGrid` read number of items selected/current selection just to pass down to `Product`, then alternative solution is to connect `Product` directly to store.

Assuming each of your product has its own id or at least index value in list

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    productData: getProductData(state, props.productId),
    isProductSelected: isProductSelected(state, props.productId)
})

const ProductWrapper = connect(mapStateToProps)(Product)
```

and then your `ProductGrid` needs to take only productIds to render the list

```
export default class ProductGrid extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
  renderProducts() {
    return this.props.productIds.map(productId => (
      <ProductWrapper productId={productId} />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderProducts()}</div>;
  }
}
```